# How would I handle the multithreading better on my request spammer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a little python script for spamming requests to a URL using Requests, It uses proxies so the IPs are random, I have a text folder called https.txt that  has over two thousand proxies that I've gotten.

I attempted to multithread the program, but I feel like what I'm doing isn't exactly ideal for what I'm doing. If I could get any advice on how to improve this, that would be much appreciated

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
import requests
import threading

init()

# constant vars
link = "" # URL goes here
agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"
referer = ""
proxies = open("https.txt", "r")

# dynamic vars
threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = []
num = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter, proxy):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.proxy = proxy
    def run(self):
        # print("Starting " + self.name)
        spam(self.name, proxy)

# Each thread runs this function once
def spam(threadName, proxy):
    try:
        headers = {
            "user-agent": agent,
            "referer": referer
        }
        req = requests.get(url=link, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=100)
        status = req.status_code
        req.close()
        if status == 200:
            print(Fore.CYAN + threadName + ": Working request with proxy: " + Fore.YELLOW + x.strip())
        else:
            print(Fore.GREEN + threadName + ": Connection Code Status Error:", status)
    except IOError :
        print(Fore.RED + threadName + ": Connection error - Bad Proxy")


for x in proxies:
    thread = str(num)
    num = num + 1
    proxy = {
        "https": x.strip()
    }
    thread = myThread(thread, "Thread-" + thread, num, proxy)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```